# How to get & use the ID of a button inside a Formview as Trigger for an Update panel Trigger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net button,fileupload control inside a formview inserttemplate and which is inside an accordion control,which is also inside an update panel.
But the fileupload.hasfile keeps returning false even though I added a file.After some googling,I understood that the  fileupload does not work with partial postbacks.I'm trying to add the asp.net button as one the triggers for postback but I keep getting this error:

```
A control with ID 'lnkBtnUpdate' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'lnkBtnUpdate' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.


Stack Trace: 
[InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'lnkBtnUpdate' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.]
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelControlTrigger.FindTargetControl(Boolean searchNamingContainers) +784600
   System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger.Initialize() +19
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection.Initialize() +82
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +230
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

How do I get the ID of the button so that I can add it as a trigger for the Update panel,futhermore,is there another way that I can use FileUpload control in an Update Panel?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
        HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
        FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250"
        FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="Fill" Height="1197px"
        Width="100%">
      <Panes>
        <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPanePlannedRoles" runat="server">
          <Header>
            View ManPower Plan
          </Header>
          <Content>
            <div id="divListView" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
              <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="pk_PersonelID"
                  DataSourceID="DSRCFormView" Style="margin-left: 0px; background-color: #EFF3FB;"
                  Width="608px" OnItemInserting="FormView1_ItemInserting" OnItemCreated="FormView1_ItemCreated">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                  <div id="titleSpan" class="titleBannerDIV">Edit Personnel</div>
                  <div style="width: 70%; float: left">
                    <table  id="one-column-emphasisB" style="background-color: #EFF3FB;padding: 1px 1px; width:100%">

                      <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                          Photo:
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left">
                          <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="tb10" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="style3" colspan="3">
                          <asp:Label ID="lblErr" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Style="font-weight: 700; text-align: left;"
                              Width="250px"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnUpdate_Click" CommandArgument='' <%#Eval("pk_PersonelID") %>'>Update
                          </asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                              Text="Finish" OnClick="UpdateCancelButton_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          &nbsp;
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>



                </EditItemTemplate>

              </asp:FormView>
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Content>
        </asp:AccordionPane>

      </Panes>
    </asp:Accordion>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>

    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBtnUpdate"  />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```